# Perform the same operation to all the variables but first variable passed in a Perl function

Tags: perl, loops, foreach, arguments, subroutine

I am using a Perl function to dump a CSV file, where I pass certain values, and indie this function, I want to perform same operation for these passed variables except for the first variable, which is the file handle.
What I want to do is to check whether a passed argument (`string`) has commas in it, if so, make enclose them in quotation mark (`"`) s.

But I need to assign these values to variable names, as I have to use them later for different purposes.

Following is my subroutine:

```
sub printCSVRowData
{
    my $CSVFileHandle = shift;

    foreach my $str (@_) {
        if ($str eq "" or not defined $str or $str =~ /^ *$/) {
            $str = "NA";
        }
        $str =~ s/\"//g;
    }

    my $firstCol = shift;
    my $secondCol = shift;
    my $thirdCol = shift;

    # Do some modifications

    print $CSVFileHandle "$firstCol, $secondCol, $thirdCol";
}
```

Now the issue is when I values to this subroutine, I get the following error message:

> Modification of a read-only value attempted at  line  (where `$str =~ s/\"//g;` is called).

Can anyone help me on this ? What am I doing wrong here ? Is there any other way around for this ?

Comment: Within your `foreach()` block, should you not be using `$elem` instead of `$str`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying `@_`, whose elements are the scalars passed as arguments. For this reason, modifying the elements of `@_` isn't safe. That's why we copy the elements of `@_` and the modify copies instead.

```
sub printCSVRowData {
    my ($csv, $fh, @fields) = @_;
    @fields = map { defined($_) && /\S/ ? $_ : "NA" } @fields;
    $csv->say($fh, \@fields);
}
```

You should be using Text::CSV_XS or similar.

```
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    auto_diag => 2,
    binary    => 1,
});
```